# Return predefined html content for https urls using LittleProxy

Tags: mitmproxy, little-proxy

I am using little proxy https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy to create a test proxy which returns some predefined html content for a given url. Code for same:

```
 HttpProxyServer server =
DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
    .withPort(8080)
    .withFiltersSource(new HttpFiltersSourceAdapter() {
        public HttpFilters filterRequest(HttpRequest originalRequest, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
            return new HttpFiltersAdapter(originalRequest) {
                @Override
                public HttpResponse clientToProxyRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {
                   // My custom implementataion to return the locally stored content based in input url
                   String content = getContent(request.getUri())
                   final ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(content, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
                   HttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, status, buffer);
                   HttpHeaders.setKeepAlive(response, false);
                   HttpHeaders.setHeader(response, "Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
                   return response;
                }

                @Override
                public HttpObject serverToProxyResponse(HttpObject httpObject) {
                    return httpObject;
                }
            };
        }
    })
    .start();
```

I am calling the proxy for a url using below code :

```
public HttpResponse performHttpGet(String url, String proxyHost, int port) throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpClient http =   HttpClients.custom().setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, port)).build();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    return http.execute(get);

}
```

For http urls the http get call is working fine but for https urls the call is failing since it makes a CONNECT request for https urls. Is there any way to return the same response for **https** urls as well in little proxy ?

How can I use MITM for this use case where I want to send some predefined content for https urls instead of making actual call to web server.

Comment: You could use the HostResolver option to modify the URL on https and the URL can server the content